# following guide to make camera app, getting errors. Android-sdk

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

So I was trying to follow http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html to create a simple app that captures video and audio and saves the file to the sd card. and have succeed. with the help of pro android 4 (pretty decent book)

Here is a github repo with the code: https://github.com/androidAwesome/Android-Camcorder

With the Help of Sam, Thanks again!, I have a working copy of a camera app that can be customized. The documentation is kinda shaky, and I think it is missing a line in the prepareVideoREcorder() method. There should be a mCamera.stopPreview(); before the mCamera.unlock() is called. Hopefully with no luck you should be able to create an android project, add a class for the SurfaceView, then copy everything in here and have a working camcorder app that you can continue to customize!

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.camera123.cr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Camera123"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 

            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

cameraPreview.java:

```
package com.camera123.cr;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Camera123.java:

```
package com.camera123.cr;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager.OnCancelListener;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class Camera123 extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private Button captureButton;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);


        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (isRecording) {
                            // stop recording and release camera
                            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                            // inform the user that recording has stopped
                            captureButton.setText("Capture");
                            isRecording = false;
                        } else {
                            // initialize video camera
                            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                                // now you can start recording
                                mMediaRecorder.start();

                                // inform the user that recording has started
                                captureButton.setText("Stop");
                                isRecording = true;
                            } else {
                                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                                releaseMediaRecorder();
                                // inform user
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
       );
    }






    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        if (c != null){
            Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
            c.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Camera did not open");
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){


        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);



        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));


        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            isRecording = false;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Null Pointer Exception tells you the exact line where the error occurs, please post the entire logcat trace if you need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will guess that you need to change this:

```
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...
```

to:

```
Button captureButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

Your Activity cannot find a view until you specify an XML file or layout to look in with setContentView().

**Addition**

You seem to have a few errors from cutting & pasting you code. Try changing this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


// Create an instance of Camera
mCamera = getCameraInstance(); // Setting this too early!
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);

setContentView(R.layout.main); // Duplicate code that will cause lots of trouble
```

To this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main); 

// Create an instance of Camera
mCamera = getCameraInstance();

// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);
```

If this helps please mark the answer as correct. Should you have more errors double check how you are cutting & pasting your code, and if you can't find it feel free to post a new question.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I noticed you try to use findViewById() incorrectly more than once... I updated my answer.

Comment: That was the ticket, however I still am experiencing a new error. startPreview failed. its complaining on this line of CameraPreview: mCamera.startPreview();

Comment: An error location is great, but I'll need the logcat information as well, since I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: I made the edits to the original post and pasted the logcat. Thanks for all your help thus far Sam!

Comment: I did those changes and added another permission to the manifest file. ultimately now my app doesnt record and it fails with prepare failed: -1. any thoughts? I updated logcat and my code in original post.

Comment: "06-21 09:54:56.465: D/DEBUG(9104): IOException preparing MediaRecorder: prepare failed." Tells us that there was an exception while preparing the MediaRecorder, but rather than crash we caught the exception and exited gracefully. So you're not building `mMediaRecorder` correctly, perhaps you just need to un-comment Step 5? I am getting very different errors about "media server died"...

Comment: heh, so I uncommented step 5. now it crashes and logcat produces new msg. I edited the original post again, havent found much on this error msg. any idea what its saying?

Comment: Simply your app has run out of memory, how to fix it is another question. Here is a [camera app](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture/) from CommonWares, you might have better luck with this code.

Comment: Unfortunately that is for capturing a photo, I need to capture video. I will look into their code see if I can adapt some of it to make mine work. I have to get this working, my custom camera app is going to be awesome for certain type of niche. Once I get this basic video camera working I will post here and create a repository on github. Thanks for all your help Sam, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: I have been debugging the code, and it is saving files now. Sometimes they will be playable (with good content) sometimes they are corrupted. Any chance u can take a look?

Comment: @androidAwesome Sure, but I might not be able to help... I suggest writing a new question that asks if anyone here knows why some files are getting corrupted.

Comment: Since I helped you with a number of errors, would you mark this as correct? (An accepted answer will rarely be perfect, but good enough to help you move ahead.)

Comment: Thanks, Im pretty new to stackoverflow. I have found plenty on help just by browsing never really asked a question. I will consider asking a new question after I get a couple more hours to try and debug it. I feel I am very close.

Comment: hey I was able to get a working copy, can you check that this works with android 2.2 on your side. I added a github repo as well. Thanks again for all your help. lemme know if there is anything else I can do for ya!

Comment: This isn't something I normally do, but I compiled the code and it runs fine on my HTC 2.3.4 device. I would only recommend changing the save location from `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` to `Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran the code on a Droid X 2.3.4 where it crashes. 
It sets *mCamera = null*  since getCameraInstance() returns null the second time it is called.
Other places in the code do not check for null so you get bugs.
Such as *CameraPreview: mCamera.startPreview();* mentioned above.
Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    if(mCamera==null) 
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
```